# How come Scalatest can be used via Junit in Scala

Tags: scala, junit, sbt, scalatest

In the build.sbt of an Example Assignment in a Scala course, the test library used is junit 4.10. There is no mention of Scalatest.

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test
```

And yet in a test class `scalatest` could be referenced and the tests could be written using actual `scalatest` syntax:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ListsSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  ...etc...
}
```

**Question**: I suppose the Scala compiler accesses `scalatest` via the `junit` library. If so, what is the reason to embed scalatest in junit?

Comment: Which Scala course is it?

Comment: Coursera: [Functional Programming in Scala Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/scala#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the assignment project from the referred course and it actually has quite complicated structure using deprecated way of defining a build in `project/*.scala` files, extending `Build`.

The answer to your question is simple though: scalatest dependency is defined in `project/CommonBuild.scala` and added to the build in `project/StudentBuildLike.scala`. So there is no magic, you're using normal scalatest and a custom test runner (see `project/ScalaTestRunner.scala`).

Comment: Oh scalatest dependency is scattered in that maze of SBT build definition. Hope the course author would modernize the build.sbt

Comment: Yep. This could have been extracted into an sbt plugin. Easier to maintain, less boilerplate and confusion for the students. But I guess "it works, so why change?"...

Comment: Why changes? The name of the course is SCALA SPECIALIZATION. This is enough reason in my opinion.